# Why do we include variables in the upper boundary of volume integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I heartily appreciate your taking a look.
[Example 1.8.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEz4Z.jpg)

When we compute volume integral, as in this example, the upper boundary is often expressed in terms of another variable, 1-y. However, I am unsure why we can't just compute the integral xdx from 0 to 1. Variable x in this example begins from 0 and ends at 1, so why not just let x run from 0 to 1?

*In this way, I found that the integral evaluates to 3/4, an incorrect answer.

Comment: For the same reason that the outer integral is $\int_0^3$ and not, say, $\int_0^4$

Comment: I'd suggest integrating over z first, as it is independent of the other two variables. Now, get the equation of the "flat" part of the prism. Do you know how to evaluate double integrals? Integrate the remaining function over the area bounded by this equation and the axes.

Comment: Thanks all for the support. The intuition of integrating over the flat part gave me an insight into the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to think about it is like this. You want to find $\iiint_R xyz^2 dV$ where $R$ is our prism shape. Now, let $A(z_0)$ be the intersection of our region $R$ with the plane $z= z_0$. In other words, $A(z_0)$ is the cross-section of the region we want to integrate where $z = z_0$. Now, we know that $z$ ranges from 0 to 3. Fubini's theorem is means that $\iiint_F xyz^2 dV = \int_0^3 \left(\iint_{A(z)} xy^2 dA\right) dz$. Essentially, we integrate $xyz^2$ over every cross-section and then integrate through all of the cross-sections. So, now what does $A(z)$ look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBjOk.jpg). So now we need to integrate $xyz^2$ over that region. But that region is a triangle, so the bounds look like $0\leq y \leq 1$ and $0\leq x \leq 1-y$. Putting all of this together, we get $\int_0^3 \int_0^1 \int_0^{1-y} xyz^2 dx dy dz$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I see the problem clearly now: when we integrate from 0 to 1 for x, the resulting cross-section is a square. However, we have a triangle, so x should be bounded between 0 and 1-y. Have a nice day!